# error status:400,body:{message:The related lists UI API currently does not support this related list while using uiRelatedListApi

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, javascript, salesforce1-app

i am trying to display a related list in an LWC that was deployed in an AppPage

This is the code :

editMaterielAlivrer.js

```
import { LightningElement, wire } from 'lwc';
import { getRelatedListRecords } from 'lightning/uiRelatedListApi';


export default class EditMaterielAlivrer extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement) {

  error;
  records;

@wire(getRelatedListRecords, {
    parentRecordId: 'a0C7f000005iNUPEA2',
    relatedListId: 'Materieaux_a_livrer',
    fields : ["Materieaux_a_livrer.Id", "Materieaux_a_livrer.Oeuvre__c"]
 })


listInfo({ error, data }) {
    if (data) {
        console.log('je suis dans data');
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
        this.records = data.records;
        this.error = undefined;
    } else if (error) {
        console.log('je suis dans error');
        console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
        this.error = error;
        this.records = undefined;
    }
}
```

}

**the parentRecordId is the contrat__c id , and the
relatedListId is the plural label of the object Materiel_a_livrer__c**

editMaterielAlivrer.html

```
<template>
<lightning-card title="Liste des matérieaux à livrer">
    <template if:true={records}>
        <div class="slds-m-around_medium">
            <template for:each={records} for:item="rec">
                <p key={rec.fields.Id.value}>
                    {rec.fields.Name.value}
                </p>
            </template>
        </div>
      </template>
   </lightning-card>
 </template>
```

editMaterielAlivrer.js-meta.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
  <apiVersion>55.0</apiVersion>
  <isExposed>true</isExposed>
  <targets>
    <target>lightning__AppPage</target>
    <target>lightning__RecordPage</target>
    <target>lightning__HomePage</target>
  </targets>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

i have created an AppPage and a button linked to the appPage

[image]

The button is added on the 'Matériels à livrer' relatedList  on the Contrat__c object
[image]

i want to see the related list records that are linked to the contract object on my component

it doesn't work
[image]
and i have this error in the log

**{status:400,body:{message:The related lists UI API currently does not support this related list,statusCode:400,errorCode:INVALID_TYPE},headers:{},ok:false,statusText:Bad Request,errorType:fetchResponse}**

any suggestions please !

FYI i am a beginner in LWC

on the relatedListId attrbute i put the plural label, it doesn't work i tried with the apiName of the object it didn't work also

Comment: check offical doc https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.reference_wire_adapters_get_related_list_records.as per doc  it should be apiname of object.  hence  it should be api name of child object.you can try with plural and singular and check if it works

Comment: by reading your question again,i think   you already tried what i wrote in previous comment. aplogies for not reading detailed question post.    if you notice in your contractt lookup   on child object  ,  you will have Child Relationship Name  field.  can you try with that  hope that will work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your wire method, you need to include the full api name of the object.

e.g

```
@wire(getRelatedListRecords, {
    parentRecordId: 'a0C7f000005iNUPEA2',
    relatedListId: 'Materieaux_a_livrer__r',
    fields : ["Materieaux_a_livrer__c.Id", "Materieaux_a_livrer__c.Oeuvre__c"]
})
```

I'm guessing at what the full api name is, but the `relatedListId` should definitely end in `__r` and the `fields` should have the `__c` in it, the same as any other field reference

Comment: it works thank you !  i've put the wrong relatedListId the correct one to put is the internal name of the related list ==> Materiels_livrer__r  and on the html i ve updated the {rec.fields.Name.value} by  <p key={rec.Id}>